# "this" keyword in a javascript module

Tags: javascript

I have defined the following module globally:

```
var module = (function () {

  console.log(this);

  this.fn = function () {
    console.log(this);
  }

  return this;
})();
```

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html :

`In JavaScript |this| always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of.`

The first call to `console.log` logs `Window` as the value of `this`, and that I understand. But, so does also the second call to `console.log`.

Since `this` refers to the owner of the function, why does `module.fn` log `Window` and not `module`?

When I call `fn` I still have to write `module.fn`, I can't write `Window.fn`. Since `this` refers to `Window` I find this confusing.

EDIT: I forgot to return `this` in my example.

Comment: How are you calling `fn`?

Comment: Like this: `module.fn();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the global object receives the `fn`. It is the `window` object in case of browsers. That is because you are *calling* the function in place (effectively constructing a new scope) without specific context.
On the end, your `module` object is just a reference to the `window` (because of `return this;`).

### What is `this`?

In JavaScript, `this` is the current context, the object on which the function was called that particular time. It is **not** the "holder" of the function. You can always "steal" the method from other objects and `apply` (literally) it to your own.

Assume you want to slice the `arguments` object for some reason. It looks just like an array, but it is NOT an array. `arguments.slice(2,4)` does not work (assuming ECMAScript < 5). What to do?

```
Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments, [2,4]);
```

You need to *steal* the `slice` function from the Array prototype, and use if on your arguments. Inside the `slice` call, the "this" is the arguments object that particular time.

### How to construct a valid module?

Your job is to `return` the module object. You do not want do mess with the context. It is not relevant, as long as you are not applying the function directly on module object.

The easiest solution is the simplest.

```
var module = (function() {
   // do something internally, great for "private" stuff

   // then return the "public" interface
   return {
       doSomething: function() {
          // do something
       },
       introduce: function() {
           console.log(this);
       }
   };
})();

module.introduce(); // Object {doSomething: function, introduce: function}
module.doSomething();
```

**The other way.**

Alternatively, you could use the `this` to do your job, using the apply, if you really want to.

```
var module = {};
(function(){
   this.doSomething = function() {
      // do something
   };
   this.introduce = function() {
       console.log(this);
   };
}).apply(module);

module.introduce(); // Object {doSomething: function, introduce: function}
module.doSomething();
```

Note this is almost equal to the "new" call.

There are more equally valid ways to do it, but the first presented one is frequently used and very clear. Anyway, everything really depends on your code conventions.

Comment: EDIT: That was a mess - point is the `return this` at the end. |

Thanks for clarifying `this`. 

I was reading this example:

`var MyModule = (function() {
  var myPrivateData = 303;
  function myPrivateFunction() {
    alert('private');
  }
  this.myPublicData = 42;
  this.myPublicFunction = function() {
    alert(this.myPublicData);
  }
  return this;
})();`

That is what confused me, I didn't understand how it would work. But it seems like it doesn't then.

Comment: @kjelelokk It looks strange. "return this;" just returns a global object, which is later assigned to the module. This is really bad if you want to have more than one module (which is the case i suppose).

Comment: Yes, I want more modules. I was refreshing ways to write modular javascript and came across that example. Seems like they forgot something in it.

Answer (score 4):

> Since this refers to the owner of the function, why does module.fn log Window and not module?

The return value of the outer function is `window` because it doesn't get called in any particular context, so `module` ends up being `window` as well.

It seems that the way you have applied the module pattern is wrong. It should be returning the public interface that gets used in the rest of your code:

```
var module = (function () {
  console.log(this);

  // public interface
  return {
    fn: function () {
      console.log(this);
    }
  }
})();

module.fn(); // "Object {fn: function}"
```

Comment: I forgot to return `this` in the example, I do it in my code. Added it now.

Comment: @kjelelokk Updated my answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern is wrong what you are doing to make a closed scope and setting `module` to the return from that scope:

```
// This is the design pattern:

var module = (function () {
  var module = {};

  var localVar = 1;

  module.moduleVar = 2;

  module.fn = function () {
    console.log(this);
  }


  return module;
})();

console.log(module.fn); // function() { console.log(this) ;}
console.log(module.moduleVar); // 2
console.log(module.localVar); // undefined
```

Comment: I forgot to return `this` in the example, I do it in my code. Added it now.